# Recovering OpenOffice files from corrupted OS

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery

I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 yesterday, and my laptop promptly froze and wouldn't respond to anything other than the power button. When I turned it back on, Ubuntu failed to work period. I can get control of the mouse, but it's just a blank screen, nothing to click on, no keyboard commands are working.

Now, I'm not too worried about this -- a reinstall will probably fix that.  The issue is that I have a brace of about twenty OpenOffice files that would make my boss very grumpy if I lost. Is there any way to recover them?

I've made a boot disk using a USB drive, but even when I boot from the flash drive, I can't see the files that need rescuing.  Is there some way to recover them? Please explain it in simple language for an inexperienced Linux user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 13.10 Live USB, you should be able to boot from it and do a repair install. During the installation process, if you select this, it will reinstall Ubuntu but keep all your original files that were in the home folder.

If you open the file manager while in a Live USB session, you should see your Ubuntu installation in the shortcut panel on the left. The users' files are in the `home` folder.

Also, if you have everything backed up to some place like Ubuntu One, it should be no trouble to restore the files.